# generate tag xml in JAVA

Tags: soap, xml-parsing, http-post, soa

How i generate tag XML like this in java to hit HTTP POS SOA ?

Parameter:

```
<opNameA>
    <Header>
        <code11>A34</code11>
        <code12>POS</code12>
    </Header>
    <opname>
        <code1>1234</code1>
        <code2>123456</code2>
        <code3>abc123</code3>
        <code4>xyz123</code4>
        <code5>78689332</code5>
        <code6>50000</code6>
        <code7>2013-11-11 10:15</code7>
    </opname>
</opNameA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either DOM or SAX parsing for generating xml in java. Please follow the below links for the basics.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/